# Drag and Drop of divs shifts wrong row of divs on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I've got a simple Drag and Drop setup for my relatively positioned divs but on resizing them using CSS's resize the elements on the old row are shifted instead of the new one. I don't want to use any libraries aside from jQuery.

Here is a fiddle showing whats happening: http://jsfiddle.net/RainyCats/6zega6zo/4/

code:

```
    <div id='container'>`
        <div id='main'></div>`
    </div>

#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.tile {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #128CAB;
    resize: both;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #CCC;
    margin: 15px;
    cursor: grab;
    overflow: auto;
}


for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var tile = "<div class='tile' draggable='true' id='" + i +"'></div>"
    $('#main').append(tile);
    $('#'+i).append('<p>'+i+'</p>');
    addListeners(document.getElementById(i));
}
function addListeners(el) {
    el.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    el.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    el.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    el.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    el.addEventListener('drop', handleDragDrop, false);
}


function handleDragStart (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('called drag start');
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'all';

    //send id of DnD source
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.id);
}


function handleDragEnter(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    console.log('called drag enter');

}

function handleDragOver(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();  
    console.log('called drag over');

}

function handleDragLeave(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('called drag leave');

}

function handleDragEnd(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('called drag end');

}

function handleDragDrop(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();   
    console.log('called drag drop');

    //get the source element and its offset
    var srcId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    var srcEl = document.getElementById(srcId);
    var srcOffset = $('#'+srcId).offset();

    var targetOffset = $('#'+this.id).offset();


    //swap the offsets of the target and source    
    var newSrcOffset = {'left':targetOffset.left, 'top': targetOffset.top};
    $('#'+srcId).offset(newSrcOffset);

    var newTargetOffset = {'left':srcOffset.left, 'top': srcOffset.top};
    $('#'+this.id).offset(newTargetOffset);
}
```

To repeat the bug drag a div from the top row to the row below it and then resize it horizontally and you will see the elements from the top row will be shifted.

The reason this is a issue is because i have other functionality like docking a div to left of the screen etc.

Any other tips/best practices are greatly appreciated.
Thanks guys!